# Can I say "I'm doing this first than you"?

Tags: grammaticality, spoken-english

I don't think you can be *first than* someone, but I was thinking like some sort of competition.

Would this be considered: The one that done it before you do?

Comment: If you do something first, you do it before everybody, no need to say before whom. If you have done something quicker than another person, but you are not the first from all the persons that did it, than you say "quicker/faster than you" or "before you". Now way you can say "*first than you".

Comment: "I will do/finish this earlier than you."

Comment: What do you mean by "the one that done it before you"?

Comment: The only I see is a typo: "I'm doing this first, then you."

Comment: No. It doesn't make sense. and it's not grammatical. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: I didn't find this sentence, is a modification that I myself made from the Portuguese. In Portuguese grammar is wrong too, we can't say it like: "Cheguei primeiro que você", we have to say: "cheguei primeiro".

Answer (score 4):

*First* is one of the few adjectives in English that does not have a comparative. It's a true absolute adjective: either something is first or it's not. You can't say *I did it firster* or *I did it more first*.

While many things that grammarians claim are absolute adjectives, like *perfect, complete,* and *true*, are really not, *first* really is one. People say *more perfect*, *more complete*, and *truer* all the time, but nobody says *firster* or *more first*.

And when you say *"**adj.** than you"*, you need a comparative. So *first than you*, and *firster than you* are both wrong.

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=firster%2C+more+first%2C+more+complete%2C+more+perfect%2C+truer&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is proof that *first* is a true absolute adjective, unlike *perfect*, *complete*, and *true*. Note that these few instances of *more first* that it finds are almost all expressions like *more first prizes*.

Comment: I suppose ***foremost = first*** and ***hindmost = last*** are "kinda" comparatives in form, if not in substance. But it's certainly worth remembering that ***first, last*** can't really be made into comparatives at all, since someone is *always* ready to point out that ***most unique***, for example, scuppers any assertion that ***unique*** is not "gradable".

Comment: @Fumblefingers: And many lists of absolute adjectives (like [this one](https://word.tips/grammar/adjectives-gradable-absolute/#tips-and-tricks-summary)) leave out the real absolute adjectives like *first, last*, and *main* because they're compiled by prescriptive grammarians trying to force their prescriptions on us, and no native English speaker would dream of saying *more first*.

Comment: Haha - telling observation! We all tend to choose examples that support our own position. (But I guess seeing the wood despite the trees is your specialist subject when it comes to sampling, representative examples, and stuff like that! :)

Comment: Incidentally, "more first" sounds like *exactly* the kind of thing an infant would come out with before they become fluent in that area.

Comment: If one argues that the non-existence of comparative/superlative forms is the most sensible way to define an 'absolute adjective' (rather than on semantic grounds), the existence of 'firstest' [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/firstest+with+the+mostest)] disqualifies 'first'. Far more useful to class 'full' say as absolute, with the usage 'fuller' as shorthand for 'more nearly full'. Murphy [[ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-absolute-adjective-1689047#:~:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20an%20absolute,always%20in%20the%20superlative%20degree.)] ...

Comment: distinguishes 'non-scalar absolutes, like 'odd', which are not modifiable, and what we'll call scalar absolutes, like 'perfect', which indicate a bounded portion of a scale.' Scalar absolutes can be used in strings like 'more nearly full', 'more nearly perfect' which are often deleted to 'more full' / 'more perfect'.

Comment: "first is a true absolute". Technically true, but there are workarounds. The most obvious is the phrase, "first among equals". Another is to describe second or third as "very nearly first", serving to indicate that the margin between first and the others was small and might perhaps be disregarded.